# Track down processes that connect through tcp (on certain ports) using auditd (in GNU/Linux)

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, gnu, auditd

I'd like to track down processes that tries to connect to a certain port (on remote host).
So, I discovered that `auditd` is very powerful for these kind of tasks. The following command instruct `auditd` to log every connect syscall:

```
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S connect
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S connect
```

The log is then stored in `/var/log/audit/`. But the content is pretty complex. There's `ausearch` that can be used to filter the log but maybe someone of you already know how to solve this.

P.S I don't want to use netstat because I want to see even the failed connections etc..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a **failed connection**? If you are thinking about port 80/443, then there is no such thing. If instead you are thinking of *ssh/ftp/telnet* connections, you do **not** need *auditd*, all the info you will ever be able to obtain are in */var/log/auth.log*.

Comment: With **failed connection** I mean when a program try to establish a TCP connection and get an RST flag in the TCP response or just no response...  I want to track down attempt to establish connections (from local to somewhere else) on certain ports

Comment: In your shoes, I would use *iptables*´ LOG queue.

Comment: thanks, seems a nice idea, but how do I specify to log the process id or similar? I looked up but seems no one do that

Answer (score 0):

Auditd's logs *do* capture process IDs (see Red Hat's [Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-understanding_audit_log_files)). However, these only came from the **server's** processes serving incoming connection requests.

However, I do not believe that there is a way to obtain PID of failed or successful connections from **clients** since it is not transmitted over the network in the first place.